# How to use an external function in event handler in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do something like this:

```
                $(div).bind('click', myFunctionWithManyManyLinesOfCode(param) );

              .....

         function myFunctionWithManyManyLinesOfCode(args){
             //50 lines of Code
           }
```

If I do this the function is executed when the code reaches the point and doesn't execute on clicks.

If I include the code from the function myFunctionWithManyManyLinesOfCode in the bind method it will be a mess of code.

Also, I've tried this, but I cannot reference variables, they are undefined

```
                $(div).bind('click',  function() {myFunctionWithManyManyLinesOfCode(param)} );
```

Comment: you should do `$(div).bind('click', myFunctionWithManyLinesOfCode)` - right now you're actually calling your function instead of passing it as a callback

Comment: Use `on()`, not `bind()`. The latter is deprecated

Comment: But what about the parameters? Oh.... I think I can create a variable to hold that data. But still it's getting a little out of Iof  I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass whatever data you want to in the following way.

This should do the trick for you. If something is unclear please write a comment.

Edit: As stated in the comments you should use on and not bind.

```js
function myFunction(e){
             console.log(e.data.id);
}
$('#example').on('click',{id: "WHATEVER"}, myFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="example">Test</button>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler the [data] parameter isn't used very often, but it's there

Comment: This is the way I use it @freedomn-m not too sure about coding conventions and usage there. However I always prefer anonymous functions if I dont use the function anywhere else in my code since it just adds useless complexity.

Comment: I was giving up already and going alternative ways. +1 and one V.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 50 lines of code are too much for one function and should be divided into smaller methods, but you can use this method:

```
var hello = () => {
 alert(123)
}
$("p").click(hello);
```

Comment: This doesn't allow passing data to the additional function - and can do without the off-topic preaching; 50 lines of code is only there to indicate it's more than they want to replicate / DRY.